# how to find and replace meta_key inside database

Tags: database, wordpress

I am trying to find and replace a meta_key _address_1 with address_1 inside wp_usermeta in my database. Is there a function or command for this? I've seen plenty online but I have no idea which one I need and I don't wanna keep breaking the database as the website is live.

Answer (score 0):

Install and activate “Better Search and Replace” plugin from WordPress admin panel. It will create a menu item under “Settings” tab with the following options.

Go to the “Search / Replace” tab of the plugin.
Enter the word you want to search in “Search for” text box.
Enter the word you want to replace with in “Replace with” text box.
Choose the database table you want to change the words. You can choose multiple tables and replace the words. Always select individual table and do the changes instead of doing at database level.
By default the entered words are case sensitive. You can enable this checkbox to make the search query case insensitive.
Ensure to uncheck the option “Replace GUIDs”. Global Unique Identifier should not be updated in “wp_posts” table.
Ensure to run in a testing mode to see how many changes will be done in which tables.
Hit “Run Search/Replace” button to run the query.
Let us take an example of moving your live to local server. In this case you should replace “http://www.yoursite.com” to “http://localhost” in all post content, postmeta and options tables.

Enter http version in “Search for” text box in point 2.
Enter https version in “Replace with” text box in point 3.
Choose the “wp_posts”, “wp_postmeta” and “wp_options” tables in point 4. If you have changed your table prefix, you should see the tables with your custom prefix.
Leave point 5 /6 unchecked.
Enable dry run in point 7.
Hot the button to run query.
This will replace all occurrences of live site URL to localhost.

ps:more ways to do it: [https://www.webnots.com/how-to-search-and-replace-words-in-wordpress-mysql-database/]